# SOLR: can we specify a field as the boost value for a record?

Tags: solr, solr-boost

I am using SOLR. I have a field called weight. I want to have this value to boost every record with. Is there any way that I can specify it in config file?

Answer (score 0):

It's is possible. I can see 3 options.

1. Use [bq](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#qf_.28Query_Fields.29) param or boost  with [function query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#Using_FunctionQuery)
2. Use [BoostQueryParser](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_4_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/search/BoostQParserPlugin.html) as on [example](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents)
3. Apply boost in [index time](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#index-time_boosts). You can use this option with update handler or DIH

In some cases I'm using either option 1 (to add boost based on date field) in other 3 (to apply a *"document class"* wide boost)

Options 1 and 3 are the easiest to store in config. 1 in search handler config, 3 in dataimport/update handler config